# What secure erase in the fastest way on Windows 10 with cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssd, powershell, batch

I have a program in QT, C++ and I want to secure erase the computer after a trigger. After this process, I do not want the old data on the SSD to be accessed by data recovery programs. I want this process to take a very short time. I'm thinking of triggering it on CMD. I used the "cipher" command but the process takes too long. How can I do it in the fastest and safest way? I am using Windows 10 not Linux.

I tried Cipher but takes too long time. If possible, I want it to be done as soon as possible with cmd or bat file.

Comment: I received "Crypto Erase" advice from other people, but since I am not an expert in this field, I did not understand much.

Comment: [`Sdelete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete)

Comment: You can’t wipe the system disk as it’s being used by Windows. In this way Windows prevents users from causing harm to the system disk intentionally. The Cipher program cannot be used to wipe your disk.

Comment: I tried using sdelete but it takes a long time @JW0914

Comment: @Ramhound After manually deleting the desired areas, I do not want the deleted files or folders to be restored with recovery programs. I tried sdelete -z and -c multiple times but still i see old files on recovery app. Is bitlocker the only solution?

Comment: How large are the files you're deleting and how long is "too long"? What sort of storage drive are these files stored on? Security like this takes time. There is no instantaneous method of what you're requesting, and there are certain limiting factors when you look at how long a given task such as this should take. Further, seeing the old files, and being able to recover their contents are different things.

Comment: The size of the files can be up to 500 GB. I am using M2 SSD. I can recover small sized old files exactly. But I can view files larger than 100 MB, some of which are completely corrupted and some of which are at least 70 percent corrupt. File names are fully readable. As you said, it is normal for it to take a long time since it is a file writing process. Actually, what I want is to prevent access to these deleted files definitively.

Answer (score 2):

Technically not an answer, as this is not a secure erase, but I think this is an X-Y problem, and I solved it differently.

What we have done is enable BitLocker with an arbitrary password, and have the option to turn that on, on demand. Even though it will take quite a while before the disk is done being encrypted, after just 1 second, there is already enough encrypted that you can no longer boot from the disk without entering a password, and for most people, seeing the bitlocker screen, it is enough to not even consider any advanced (paid) data recovery.

So once you trigger the encryption, and then just force a reboot, the computer is locked out. True, one can still format the disk and remove all data, but most people will consider the data unrecoverable.